# jQuery - selector on new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble to access elements in a new window opened with $window.open() :

```
var printWindow = window.open(window.location.href, 'Imprimer', config = 'width=1024, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no');

printWindow.onload = function() {
    printWindow.find(".navbar").remove();
}
```

Here, the line `printWindow.find(".navbar").remove();` doesn't work. I tried several jQuery selectors, but didn't manage to access the ".navbar" which is in my popup.

By the way, AngularJS is also used in this application, maybe it has something to do with my problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where is .navbar defined?

Comment: BTW, what is: `$window` ??? Do you mean: `window` instead?!

Comment: @RUJordan .navbar is defined im my page, the current one that i'm trying to reopen in a new window with window.open(window.location.href).

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, I meant window.

Answer (score 0):

`printWindow` has no `find()` method, it's not a jQuery collection ?

```
var printWindow = $window.open(window.location.href, 'Imprimer', config = 'width=1024, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no');

printWindow.onload = function() {
    $(printWindow.document.body).find(".navbar").remove();
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't seem to work : my navbar element isn't removed, and I can't find() any element of my page. Also, no error message in the JS console.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make printWindow a jQuery object.

```
$(printWindow.document).find(".navbar").remove();
```

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't seem to work : my navbar element isn't removed, and I can't find() any element of my page. Also, no error message in the JS console.

Comment: @11OClock, make sure you follow the rule of `same origin policy` and read other details from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)